# Use my class object as JSON in python

Tags: python, json, object

I have class 'player' which has several int and string filds. How to encode it as JSON object?

Comment: Can you please give some example code of the class you are using?

Comment: What you would need to do is map each of the classes properties to key:value pairs.

Comment: class Players:
    name = ''
    position = ''
    points = ''
    min = ''
    fgm_a = ''
    threePm_a = ''
    ftm_a = ''
    oreb = ''
    dreb = ''
some filds are string and some int.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in a `default` method to the JSON encoder:

```
import json


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number


def encode_json(o):
    if isinstance(o, Player):
        return o.__dict__

        # or, alternatively ...
        return {
            'name': o.name,
            'number': o.number,
        }

    raise TypeError('Cannot serialize object of type %s' % type(o))

doc = {'team': [
    Player('Joe', 1),
]}
print(json.dumps(doc, default=encode_json))
```

In many cases, simply returning [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) will suffice. If you need additional information (say, the class name) or do not want to encode everything (maybe a Player object can hold a password you don't want to give out), simply define your own result as shown after `# or, alternatively`.

Comment: it is working, thx! Can u just explain to me how this parametar  'default = encode_json' working without passing his object parametar?

Comment: @Sejn `encode_json` is a function. In Python, functions are objects like any other. Instead of actually calling the function as `encode_json(something)` would do, we let the `json.dumps` method call the function with the parameters it deems fit.

Comment: I get it. But i still dont get how this function encode_json works. End this o, is that some special object or what?

Comment: `json.dumps` can only handle `str`, `int`, `tuple`, `list`, and `dict`. `json.dumps` calls the passed function when cannot handle an object. The only argument to the function is the object that `json.dumps` has been asked to encode. This passed function (here called `encode_json`) can then either return an object that `json.dumps` *can* handle, or throw a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

If all the members of the object should be converted (i.e. you don't have extra members used for optimizations like cached values) then you can just use

```
json.dumps(obj.__dict__)
```

for the loader may be it's better to add also a member containing the class name if this is not implied by the context...

```
d = obj.__dict__.copy()
d['classname'] = obj.__class__.__name__
return json.dumps(s)
```

If the object however also contains references to other objects then you must decide first a schema to use when passing these releations (e.g. serializing those members to `JSON` using an object ID value). Using recursive serialization may be acceptable if your data structure is just a tree and not a general graph of references.